# How to run C code repeatedly until get some stdout?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to debug a certain case of my code which is run by random process.

So I put printf in my code in the part which I want to debug.

Is there any way to run this code on terminal until I get the printf statement?

I want to run shell program like

```
while true;
if [ "$(./mycode || grep "statement")"];
then break;
done;
```

(It is not runnable, I just wanted to tell you the semantics.)

But I guess every return value in if statement falls in true.

Comment: At the very least, you want `|`, not `||`.

Comment: Agree with `|` comment. Also your `mycode.c` should honor shell conventions for its internal `exit` statements (the opposite of `C`-lang function conventions), i.e. `exit 0` for success, `exit (nonZeroCode)` to indicate problem. Good luck.

Comment: @chepner Ah yes, it's a typo. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to quit as soon as you see the line in question it's best to avoid `grep`. It may have an internal buffer and try to read past the matching line. The same goes for `sed`, and most other programs in fact.

I would use an explicit `while read` loop. `read` never reads more than one line so it won't overshoot.

```
#!/bin/bash

./mycode | while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line == *'statement'* ]] && break
done
```

The syntax may look odd, piping output into a loop. It works because a loop is really just one big compound command. It's a neat trick, really.

If you want to make it more readable you could refactor the loop into a function.

```
#!/bin/bash

read_until() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        [[ $line == *"$1"* ]] && break
    done
}
```

```
./mycode | read_until 'statement'
```

Notes:

- I'm using bash features above so you'll need a `#!/bin/bash` shebang line to use them.
- `IFS= read -r` is standard boilerplate to make the `read` call safer. `IFS=` prevents it from stripping leading whitespace, and `-r` tells it to leave backslashes alone. For historical reasons these are opt-out features not opt-in.

Comment: Actually, my intention was running the entire code multiple times (not once) until I get the statement. But now I'm trying to solve my problem by applying this code properly.